# Wrong group_id when trying to programmatically adding group to customer

Tags: customer, customer-group, group

I created a module in order to add a group to a customer depending on his profession (I added a field where he can choose between different professions).

```
<?php

class Solumed_Customer_Model_Customer_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    /*
     * observer for the customer saved event
     */
    public function customer_save_before($observer)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

            switch ($customer->getProfession()) {

                case 4:
                    $customer->setData('group_id', 4);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    $customer->setData('group_id', 5);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    $customer->setData('group_id', 6);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    $customer->setData('group_id', 7);
                    break;              

                case 8:
                    $customer->setData('group_id', 8);
                    break;

                default:
                    # code...
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log( "customer_save_before observer failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The problem is that, after creating a new customer, the group doesn't match the chosen profession. For instance, when I create a doctor (group id number 6), the customer group is not "doctor" but something else (nurse).

I tried to see what the code below give when adding a customer so I wrote this code:

```
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load(6)->getCustomerGroupCode();
```

It returns 'doctor' so I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: 1) Your switch portion is useless, it'd be quicker to check for the default case and otherwise assign the value to group_id.
2) Have you checked what group_id is assigned to the user in DB? What is the field you added in the DB?

Comment: Indeed, it's useless, I changed it to: 
$customer = $observer->getCustomer();
$customer->setData('group_id', $customer->getProfession());

To answer your second point, I'm new with Magento so I used a module that allowed me to add custom fields to customers. I just saw that the field's visible but not in the system (here is a picture to describe that):
http://puu.sh/kZn1O/007fdcc0cb.png

The field is "profession". I don't know if the problem can come from it or not. I checked the group_id in DB and it's not correct. When I add the profession with id 9, it's id 7, with id 8, it's 3 in DB, etc.

Comment: I forgot to say that I used this module to add fields to customers: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes.html

Comment: The "Système" column indicates whether or not an attribute is native to Magento, so don't worry about that :) . Please make sure that the <option> ID's do match the attribute value IDs in the DB. Otherwise you'll get mixed results.

Comment: How can I check that in the DB? It is quite big and I'm just a beginner in Magento :p

Comment: You can get the `attribute_id` in `eav_attribute`. Then check that the value you want in `eav_attribute_option_value` (with `attribute_id`) is alright. Then check that the `option_id` (in the previous table) belongs to your user, in the "value" field of `customer_entity_varchar`

Comment: I've search into DB's eav_attribute_option_value table in order to compare the option id and the group id in administration.
And I can see that they are, most of them, different. When I add a new customer, a nurse, the group_id of this group is 4 in admin. In DB, nurse has an option id of 9. But when I check the newly created user in admin, his profession is "physiotherapist" and its group_id in admin is 9.
I tried with a surgeon. It's group_id in admin is 5, in DB, 4 for option_id. In admin, nurse id is 4, then the member's a nurse.
Why are the id differents and how can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution so I am sharing it here, it may not be optimal.
Like I said previously, the problem was that, the groups ID were different.

- In *'eav_attribute_option_value'*, for a nurse I get 9
- In *'Customer_group'*, I get 4

So first I retrieved the value of the attribute corresponding to the id of the drop down list (cf. 9 for a nurse).
Then I got a list of all the names of the groups and once I found the nurse, I take the id to, finally, record it in the customer's 'group_id'.

Here's the code (like I said, it's not optimal :p):

```
try {
            $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
            $profession = $customer->getProfession();
            $groups = Mage::getModel('customer/group');

            $codeProfession = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setStoreFilter()
            ->join('attribute', 'attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id', 'attribute_code')
            ->getItemById($profession)
            ->getData()['value'];

            $group_code = $groups->load($groupName, 'customer_group_code')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->getData();

            $idProfession = 8;
            for ($i=0; $i < count($group_code); $i++) { 
                if ($group_code[$i]['customer_group_code'] == $codeProfession) {
                    $idProfession = $group_code[$i]['customer_group_id'];
                }
            }

            $customer->setData('group_id', $idProfession);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log("customer_save_before observer failed: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

Thanks for the previous help.
Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it should be like

```
try {
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $customerModel = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
    if($customerModel->getProfession())
    {
       $customerModel->setGroupId($customerModel->getProfession(), $customerModel->getStoreId())->save();
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log("customer_save_before observer failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It returned this fatal error:
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\Website\lib\Varien\Object.php on line 117

Comment: How did you try it? can you show it here please?

Comment: Yes, I did it like that:
`try {
   $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

   switch ($customer->getProfession()) {
    default:
     $customer->setGroupId($customer->getProfession(), $customer->getStoreId())->save();
     break;
   }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
   Mage::log( "customer_save_before observer failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
  }`

Comment: edited my answer. try it

Comment: Well, that's strange. This time, there's no error but it gives me the same profession, always. I chose 'nurse', it gives 'General', try 'doctor', same. :/ Maybe the attribute is not added correctly in the DB. I used a module to do that but maybe it isn't good, how can I check if the attribute exists in DB?

Comment: Check in admin for the customer if attribute is set properly or not.